# How to deal with real large numbers which don't fit in 128 bits in Rust without loss?

Tags: rust

When I try to do 10 power 100, I get

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to multiply with overflow', shorter.rs:33
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

which is normal because 10^100 is greater than 2^64 (and even 2^128).

Comment: That will naturally depend on your use case. Knowing they can go over `10^100` isn't enough. Would those be integers or real numbers? Is precision loss tolerable? Have you searched for a suitable "big number" type at crates.io? Overall, right now I cannot imagine a good answer that would not attempt to cover every possible approach. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're definitely only working with integers you can use either `BigInt` or `BigUint` from the [big_int](https://crates.io/crates/num) crate. An example usage could be:

```
extern crate num_bigint;
use num_bigint::{BigInt, Sign};

fn main() {
    let x = BigInt::new(Sign::Plus, vec![1, 0]);
    println!(num::pow(x, 100).to_str_radix(10));
}
```

Comment: How about `let x: BigInt = 10.to_bigint().unwrap()` for the first line?

Comment: That may well work or be better, I'm not all that familiar with Rust TBH.

Comment: broken link, [new link](https://crates.io/crates/num)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'll update the post link to point to the one you provided :)